# g++ complains "does not give a valid preprocessing token" on a macro while vc++ compiles fine

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, g++

Consider the following C++ Program which compiles with VC++ but fails to compile with g++

```
D:\temp>cat test.cpp
#define SET_ALLIGN_FN(what)                            \
        void set_##what##_fn() { }
        SET_ALLIGN_FN(Left);
#undef SET_ALLIGN_FN
    template<class _Arg> struct Smanip{
            Smanip(void( *pFun)(_Arg), _Arg val):m_pFun(pFun), m_val(val) { }
        void( *m_pFun)(_Arg);
        _Arg m_val;
    };
    template<>  struct Smanip<void> {
        Smanip(void( *pFun)()) : m_pFun(pFun) { }
        void( *m_pFun)();
    };
#define SET_ALLIGN(what)                                      \
    static Smanip<void>  ##what##Allign()                     \
    { return (Smanip<void>(set_##what##_fn)); }
    SET_ALLIGN(Left);
#undef SET_ALLIGN

int main() {  }
D:\temp>cl test.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.61030 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.61030.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe
test.obj

D:\temp>g++ test.cpp
test.cpp:15:23: error: pasting ">" and "Left" does not give a valid preprocessin
g token
     static Smanip<void>  ##what##Allign()  { return (Smanip<void>(set_##what##_
fn)); }
                       ^
test.cpp:16:5: note: in expansion of macro 'SET_ALLIGN'
     SET_ALLIGN(Left);
     ^
```

What I am failing to understand is why g++ complains about invalid token. The compiler highlights `>`, but that isn't a macro generated code.

Comment: The g++ error is correct; the result of a token paste must be a single preprocessing token. `>what` is two tokens.   (Compilers are allowed to provide extensions so long as they don't alter the behaviour of any conforming program though, so VC++ could support extra stuff in the preprocessor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
static Smanip<void>  ##what##Allign()
```

you try to concatenate `>` and `what`. Try to use

```
static Smanip<void>  what##Allign()
```

Comment: I wonder why VC++ did not complain to me on the first instance.